# Ruby syntax error when try to puts literal hash

Tags: ruby, syntax-error, literals, puts, ruby-2.3

Could someone explain to me why in ruby console (version 2.3.4)
trying to print hashes
these work:

```
puts({a: 'a', b: 'b'})
puts(a: 'a', b: 'b')
puts a: 'a', b: 'b'
puts [a: 'a', b: 'b']  <<< array length 1 with value of hash
puts Hash[a: 'a', b: 'b']
```

but none of these work:

```
puts {a: 'a', b: 'b'}
puts {:a => 'a', :b => 'b'}
puts{:a => 'a', :b => 'b'}
```

gives error:

> syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting '}'
>
> puts {a: 'a', b: 'b'}
>
> _ _ _ _ _ _^

And these:

```
 puts {:a => 'a'}
 puts {a: 'a'}
 puts{a: 'a'}
```

also error with:

> syntax error, unexpected =>, expecting '}'
>
> puts {:a => 'a'}
>
> _ _ _ _ _ ^

It was my understanding () around functions were entirely optional and up to the developer's style preferences.

And that {} around hashes were mostly optional, but never required to NOT be used.

I could understand if the interpreter were confused between 1 or 2 hashes (since puts takes 1+ arguments), but it just dies.

To make matters worse:
these work:

```
 puts({a: 'a', b: 'b'}, [:d, :e])
 puts ({a: 'a', b: 'b'})
```

but these do not:

```
 puts ({a: 'a', b: 'b'}, [:d, :e])
 puts (Hash[a: 'a', b: 'b'], [:d, :e])
```

Can anyone explain what is actually going on behind the scenes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ruby has a glitch because it's too permissive with parentheses. You can leave them off nearly anything, but...

`puts{}` parses as "call `puts` with a block `{}`." A block, in turn, must contain complete statements, not a comma `,` separated list. So you get the wrong syntax error.

The fix is just `puts({})`

Next, `puts ()` parses as "`puts` followed by a single argument, in parentheses." So, again, the parser cannot deal with comma `,` inside the parenthesis. The fix is to take out the space: `puts()`

Comment: This ^ or assigning the hash to a variable and then logging it as `puts varname` makes the broken ones work as well.

Comment: So I guess the takeaway from this is that hash literals can be confused with ruby blocks?

Comment: yes; and that Ruby is slightly space sensitive. `puts()` differs from `puts ()`.

Comment: IMO the takeaway from this is that making parenthesis contextually optional was just a bad idea in the first place.  No hate on Ruby; it's a great language; I've just never been sold on this particular choice.  :P